# Export page with PrimeFaces line and pie charts to PDF

Tags: jsf, pdf, primefaces, charts, reporting

I have a page with line and pie charts and I would like to generate a PDF report with those charts. How can I achieve this? I tried with `<p:dataExporter>`, but it works only on tables.